# WebSphere: An error occured while initializing MyFaces: null

Tags: jsf, myfaces, websphere-9

While running Jsf application, i am getting below error.

> An error occured while initializing MyFaces: null
>                                    java.lang.NullPointerException   at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:143)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:119)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1836)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:442)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1248)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1575)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:704)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1150)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:800)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2317)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5574)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5700)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2322)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
>     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)

How should i fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Please copy-paste the relevant part of the stacktrace in a search engine and start investigating. Stacktraces/errors are excelent keywords . https://www.google.com/search?q=An+error+occured+while+initializing+MyFaces%3A+null+java.lang.NullPointerException+at+org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java%3A62)

Comment: solution above exception, created separate shared library for prime faces.

Comment: Please create a full answer!